# rabbitmqctl returns error on docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I have this config in my docker-compose.yml:

```
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.5.1-management
    ports:
        - "${CPF_RABBITMQ_PORT}:5672"
        - "${CPF_RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_PORT}:15672"
    environment:
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
        - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
```

Rabbitmq server is working properly. But when the server is up and I enter the container to use rabbitmqctl I got the following error:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@0928435c3767: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@0928435c3767]

rabbit@0928435c3767:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on 0928435c3767
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
  * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-277@0928435c3767'
- home dir: /root
- cookie hash: cE9wdMxW96ogqvZmxND6cA==
```

What I'm missing? Shoudn't it "just works" ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. If you upgrade rabbitmq container it just works. 
I changed the line:

```
image: rabbitmq:3.5.1-management
```

To:

```
image: rabbitmq:3-management
```